# Use Azure to GET from RESTful API

Tags: rest, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I would like to use Azure to retrieve JSON data from a REST api then store that data into a table.  Data retrieval would occur daily and a parameter would be passed to the api to restrict the results to the prior day's data.

Which Azure component/mechanism should I use for calling the api?

The data would be the foundation for a data warehouse.  Should I use Azure SQL table or Azure table?

I have recently begun exploring Azure and am not sure how to do this.

I look forward to feedback.
Thank you.

Comment: Azure isn't software or a library just like Amazon or Google aren't. You need to write the program that will call whatever REST API you want and process the results

Comment: While properly formulated, this question is not a good fit for Stackoverflow. It's primarily based on opinions/experience and without knowing the entire context, it's impossible to answer. You might have better luck asking in http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Azure Functions. You can create an Azure Function that is periodically invoked, it has input bindings for different sources (or you can add some C# code to read from URL) and then place results into Azure Database.

Here is example of Azure Function that sends JSON to stored procedure:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169531/Sending-events-from-Azure-Event-Hub-to-Azure-SQL-D